# Alternative proof check: $(A + B)/A \cong B / (A \cap B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

It is a well-known fact that $(A + B)/A \cong B / (A \cap B)$ for $R$-submodules $A,B$ of an $R$-module $M$. A [previous Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009780/what-is-b-a-cap-b-for-r-submodules-a-b-of-an-r-module-m) offers a rigorous proof. I have come up with the following alternative proof by set manipulations on the basis of $A$ and $B$, and I am not sure if this is correct or rigorous:

Choose a basis $V_A$ of $A$ and $V_B$ of $B$ such that $V_A - (V_A \cap V_B)$ is orthogonal to $V_B - (V_A \cap V_B)$. Then the basis of $A + B$ is $V_A \cup V_B$. Let "$-$" denote the set exclusion operation. Then the quotient operation $(A+B)/A$ is equivalent to $V_{A+B} - V_A = V_A \cup V_B - V_B = V_B - (V_A\cap V_B) = V_B - V_{A \cap B}$, where the second equality is achieved by set theory and the last expression is precisely the basis of $B / (A \cap B)$. Therefore, the basis of $(A + B)/A$ and $B / (A \cap B)$ have the same cardinality and therefore these vector spaces are isomorphic. $\blacksquare$

This proof appeals to me because I can express vector space additions and quotients in a Venn diagram. Is this proof correct?

Comment: What do you mean by orthogonal? If you are working in an arbitrary vector space (or R-module) this notion may not make sense. Also, you should be clear whether you mean for $A$ and $B$ to be $R$-modules or vector spaces.

Comment: This is OK in finite-dimensional inner product (vector) spaces. With general modules, though, not every module is free, which means not every module has a basis! This proof is also a bit less "nice" in that the isomorphism it constructs is not as canonical.

Comment: @walkar and izaak Nice catch! I didn't know the important and interesting distinction that every vector space is free, but, not every module. Now I know that I need to argue $R$-modules and vector spaces differently. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to argue them differently; you can prove that if $R$ is a local ring, then the length of $(A+B)/B$ is the same as the length of $A/A\cap B$, and use that if $R=k$ is a field, then length as a $k$-module and dimension as a $k$-vector space are always the same.